# Bad memory allocation in vector

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management

Have a look at this code:

```
int main()
{
    int m;
    cin >> m;
    vector<int> cnt(m +1,0);
}
```

Now if i take m=999999298(which is an int,right?). Why am I getting an"bad memory allocation" error in the vector?.

Comment: are you building a 32-bit application? You are allocating 4GB of memory, you might only be allowed 2GB per application.

Comment: What if you take a much smaller value? Does it work then? If so, then what's the threshold at which it stops working?

Comment: `sizeof (int)` is nowadays usually 4 (32 bit). 999999298 * 4 = 3999997192 Bytes = 3906247.26 KB = 3814.69 MB = 3.72 GB. If you are on 32 bit platform this is probably not allocatable. Even on 64 bit, there might be not enough contiguous memory available.

Comment: @Scheff: That's theoretically possible, of course, but it would require 4 billion prior allocations with 3.71 GB holes in between them.

Comment: @MSalters OK. Forget about what I told about 64 bit. OP didn't mention OS and platform but stated about bad-alloc issue. So, it's probably a 32 bit platform. (It would be easier if OP could add this info.)

Comment: @MSalters I must admit that I cannot remember when I have seen a bad-alloc error in our software last time. (Must be decades ago.) What I have seen sometimes, is continuous memory consumption until RAM is exhausted. The OS (Windows 10 in my case) starts to swap to harddisk which slows down everything significantly until the whole OS seems to be frozen (and even is not able to update the mouse pointer according to mouse movement). At this point, I usually restart computer after a short time of waiting and try again with a smaller problem size... ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
vector<int> cnt(m +1,0);
```

The declaration of `vector` you have tries to allocate 999999299 **integer** elements each of which has value 0. Considering the size of integer as 4 bytes, this is about 3.7 GB of memory. It appears that your application is not allowed that much memory. That is why you get the "bad memory allocation" error.

As to why there is such a limit, you can read this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1163749/why-do-32-bit-processes-have-a-2-gb-ram-limit) and its answers.